# Mysql database not showing up in mysql workbench when querying all databases

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I created a schema in mySQL called ASSIST_DB which is not showing up as a database. I tried connecting mysql to c# in VS 2019, but I believe the database name is the problem, as the connection always fails. I queried the database connection, and it shows names of other databases and not my schema. I did google what a schema was, and it does differ from a database, but I believe that that is the database, and I do not imagine why it does not show up.
My c# connection code is as follows:

```
 //Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "ASSIST_DB";
        uid = "root";
        password = "CHANGED IT TEMPORARILY";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = @"SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD= " + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

I have uploaded a few images to make the situation clearer:

[My assist db schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcZp1.png)

[it does not show my assist_db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqXDm.png)

[connection is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL3P8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I had made a local model that was not part of my server's schemas, and had to remake the table in the server. I copied the sql code from the model I created to move the tables over. It is working perfectly now.